# How to see an animation in the PDF window of TeXShop?

Tags: texshop, animate

I'm learning something about the ''animate'' package and I've some trouble in visualizing the result of my work.  I write the code with TeXShop Version 2.47 that, after the compilation of the code, opens a PDF page where I can see the result. But, In this window, I cannot start the animation and I can see only a static, first frame, image.  If I open the PDF document with Adobe Reader,  all works right and I can see the animation.  But it is a bit awkward.

Maybe that my version of TeXShop is old? Or I've to set some option that I don't know?

Comment: The current version is 3.58

Comment: However, the documentation of `animate` says “The final PDF can be viewed in current Adobe Readers on all supported platforms (except mobile devices) or in PDF-XChange Viewer.”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The PDF previewer of TeXShop uses Apple's PDF libraries and animations are not supported; neither Preview nor Skim are able to reproduce them.

The documentation of `animate` says

> The final PDF can be viewed in current Adobe Readers on all supported platforms (except mobile devices) or in PDF-XChange Viewer.

Comment: With the `[2016-07-27]` update, Foxit Reader adds to the list.

Comment: I just tried PDF XChange Viewer version 2.5 (Jan 24 2018), and it did not play the animations I have inside PDF. Only Adobe reader did.?